# sticky css footer with 100% height content container.

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am using this technique for a sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

I wanted to create a border around my entire site that also encapsulates the footer but has passing around the entire page but ended up with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwTT.jpg

Notice how the white box is not moving down to the footer.

Here is the jsfiddle showing this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hc3Xu/14/

*I had previously asked a similar question not realizing it was the footer and I got an answer telling me that it is the  height: auto !important; in the container class that was the cause of the contentcontainer not stretching to 100%. Removing that however causes a problem with the footer not being set to the bottom of the page. So I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Show, please, design. How exactly it should look like?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. This is what I am hoping to accomplish: http://i.imgur.com/Dn3Rn.jpg

Comment: hey, man. I'm having the same problem. used the same sticky footer solution and have two-column content that I want to stretch. Have you managed to make it work? :)

Comment: there is a dirty workaround using images as background if you want pure css. js is much easier there. which one do you want? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.container {min-height:100%;  height: auto !important; height:100%;
           margin: 0 auto -30px;  width:980px;
           background:URL(images/bg_sides.jpg) repeat-y #f4f4f4;}
```

try something like:

```
.container {min-height:100%;  height: auto !important; 
           margin: 0 auto -30px;  width:980px; 
           box-shadow: inset #f4f4f4 0 0 0 20px, #BDBDBD 0 0 3px 3px;
           -webkit-box-shadow: inset #f4f4f4 0 0 0 20px, #BDBDBD 0 0 3px 3px;
           -moz-box-shadow: inset #f4f4f4 0 0 0 20px, #BDBDBD 0 0 3px 3px;}
```

You'll then also need to tweak the left and top margins of the footer to bring it in line with your contentContainer div.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5geM/

Comment: There is a problem. the footer is now being overlapped by the content in the white div.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the problem? It would also help if you applied a 1px border to your inner divs, so it's easier to see what's overlapping where.

Comment: If you give the footer div a background color, you'll see it overlapping the content in .wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hc3Xu/16/

I've changed the elements a bit to have the background image on your `html` element and the `body` be the main, centered content area. By giving it a border and changing its box-sizing, it creates that grey border around the outside while still maintaining it's 100% height. Just a slight tweak to the position of the footer moving it down 20 or so pixels makes it line up within the body's grey border area.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need a more thorough explanation of why this works.

Comment: This seems to cause the border to take up the entire left side of the screen though? http://i.imgur.com/Wuqy8.jpg